# Lua small script for a bot - issues getting it right

Tags: lua, bots

I am using a little bot for auto-betting on betting websites and I'm trying to create a script for it that's going to indicate the bot how and when to bet.

What I'm having trouble with is this: The bot has a money balance and everytime you lose or win, that balance goes down and up... what I want to do is when my balance is 3% percent lower that what it was at the beginning, the bot has to stop and then start again, and I want that balance to be updated everytime I loose, so if I have 5 balance, I want to stop when I loose 3% of 5, after I lose 3% of five, I want it to stop after I loose 3% of 4.85 and so on... Can you please help me?

I tried with

```
balancepercent = balance*(97/100)

if balance < balancepercent then
stop()
start()
```

It stops betting, but it doesn't start again.

Also, I tried with sleep(5000) but the balance doesn't update and after I loose 3% of my balance, it sleeps for 5 seconds, makes another bet, sleeps again for 5 seconds, makes another bet nad so on...

Please help me out if you know how, thank you very much!

Comment: What do `stop` and `start` do? You tried with `sleep(5000)` where? What `sleep` function is this? What environment is this? There isn't nearly enough information in this post for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Please put the complete snippet. This wouldn't run as the if block is missing an `end`. This is important to understand if you put the sleep and the stop inside or outside the if.